# Hiding Vimeo controls and replacing with play/pause toggle button

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to follow this tutorial (http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/cssplay-tutorial-vimeo-hide-controls.html) but the fiddle I created with its code doesn't seem to work. I'm not sure what I'm missing.

https://jsfiddle.net/uxhxdcwp/

```
 <div class="overlay">
   <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/134945180?
    api=1&player_id=video" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen 
    mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen id="video"></iframe> 

    <div class="playpause start"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues:

1. You have accidentally left out the closing brackets `});` in your script, resulting in an `unexpected end of script` error
2. Do not load scripts using `<script>` tag in your fiddle. Instead, use the external resource panel. However, since the plugin is **not served over a secured connection**, I have placed the actual plugin code before the start of your JS.

And now it works: https://jsfiddle.net/uxhxdcwp/1/

Comment: Ah! Cool beans. Thxs.